# Excel - How can I get a count of simultaneous activities happening in the same time period?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get a count of the various stages of a project happening during different months, but I'm unsure where to even begin. I know what I'm trying to visualise, but I can't seem to grasp how to do it.

Current Data:
[image: Current Data]

In the end what I need is a data set that will potentially show the following (not real data);

End Product:
[image: End Product]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula `COUNTIFS()`:

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!$B:$B,$A2,Data!$C:$C,"<="&B$1,Data!$D:$D,">="&B$1)
```

In the formula above the current data is in a Tab called `Data`.

Answer (score 1):

Try Pivot table.
Insert - Pivot Table - Then drag your date to the columns, drag stage to your rows, and then drag stage to your values (the default should be count of Stage, if not, manually choose that).
The data is just a sample, not as same as yours. If you only need date function, you could remove the Months.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yhZ4.png)

[How the pivot table setting look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXX6u.png)